# Why are NBr3 and NI3 unstable, but NF3 is stable?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Why are NBr3 and NI3 unstable, but NF3 is stable? Is there any reasoning behind the stability? I found that one nitrogen can accommodate fluorine easily, but not the others. Also, I don't understand what is meant by "accommodate."

Comment: Imagine taking a ping-pong ball and three basketballs, then trying to get all three basketballs to touch the ping-pong ball at the same time. Do you think there would be enough space around the ping-pong ball to fit the basketballs?  In other words, can a ping-pong ball *accommodate* three basketballs at once? Probably not. A similar thing happens when large atoms try to surround small atoms in molecules, with some complications due to the fact that atoms are not hard spheres.

Comment: ‘Why is A unstable even though B is stable?’ is not a question that gets us far …